# MySQL update error when connecting to FileMaker server via ODBC

Tags: php, mysql, odbc, filemaker

i want to update data over ODBC from mysql-Server to Filemaker-Server.

But  i am getting this error:

**There is an error in the syntax of the query., SQL state 4200 in SQLExecDirect in ........**

here is my code:

// ID_FM is numeric
// FM_Name is String

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT ID_FM, FM_Name, FM_Str, FM_Adr FROM FM_Table WHERE FM_Tr=7");    
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ID_FM = $row["ID_FM"];
    $FM_Name = $row["FM_Name"];  

    // and so on ...  


$update = "UPDATE FM_Table SET FM_Name='" . $FM_Name . "', FM_Str='" . $FM_Str . "', FM_Adr='" . $FM_Adr . "' WHERE ID_FM=" . $ID_FM;   
$dataupd = odbc_exec($conn, $update);
```

thank you!

Comment: Add the complete error massage not only a Fragment. Also learn about prepared statments

Comment: Check in FileMaker if FM_Tr is number. If it is not the case you will need to quote the number you are passing.

Comment: here is the complet error message:Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:118): There is an error in the syntax of the query., SQL state 42000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\.... on Line 12

Comment: @_Nicolai Kant FM_Tr is a number

Comment: You have two SQL statements - which one is causing the error?